# Need help to prevent python from closing after sys.exit(1) command

Tags: python, google-chrome, pywin32

Well I am very programatically illiterate, but I am giving my best to recover passwords from Chrome Login Data file, using python. however I have many many issues one of which is: there is a code for decryption [here](https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/chrome-decrypter/blob/master/chrome_decrypt.py), but after I type sys.exit(1) python closes and I can't conntinue inserting the code. I tried several other options as well but this looks like the most viable. Is there any kind of solution?

Comment: so don't type `sys.exit(1)`. because that indeed will terminate the python interpreter.

Comment: but will the rest of the code be valid without it

Comment: May i know why you are using sys.exit? Do you want to close python program or terminate a function or something else? Please elaborate your question with code that will be useful to give you a better answer.

Comment: well, I am just retyping the code (except for the things which changed from python 2.7 as I am using 3.6): This is the code https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/chrome-decrypter/blob/master/chrome_decrypt.py

Comment: See sys.exit will terminate the program so if you want to continue after getting the exception comment sys.exit

Comment: Or you could wrap `sys.exit(1)` in a `try: except SystemExit: pass` block. :)